# What the effect of thermal diffusivity on temperature rise during friction

Tags: thermodynamics

If we have two material in friction wich metal will produce the temperature?the metal with lower diffusivity or with higher diffusivity will be the source of temperature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) is the ratio of heat conduction ability to heat storage ability of a material at constant pressure.  A high ratio indicates that the material will conduct heat away more readily than it can retain the heat.  A low ratio indicates that the material has a great capacity to store heat, and will not be able to conduct heat away as rapidly.

Friction, of course, is caused by both materials.  Both materials contribute to the temperature rise caused by friction.  But the material with lower thermal diffusivity will tend to retain more heat than the material with high thermal diffusivity.  So the temperature rise will be attributable to the low diffusivity material to a greater extent than to the high diffusivity material.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer ...it helped me alot i really appreciate that